# show page not found on browser request

Tags: java, http, dataoutputstream

I'm trying to show 404 page not found from server

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ex1 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final int BUFFER_SIZE=1000;
    char[] buffer=new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(16000); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 16000");
        System.exit(-1); 
    }
    while (true) {
        Socket clientSocket = null; 
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for Connection"); 
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
            DataOutputStream output =new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \r\n");
            output.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/html \r\n\r\n");


            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to accept connection");
            System.exit(-1); 
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            in.read(buffer);
            System.out.println(buffer);
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close(); 
            System.out.println("Connection terminated");
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Problem in communicating with the client"); }
    }
}
}
```

the problem is when i type localhost:16000 into my browser (google chrome) i get "Oops! This link appears to be broken."
not page 404

output is:

```
Waiting for Connection
Connection Accepted
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Problem in communicating with the client
Waiting for Connection
Connection Accepted
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:16000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3


Connection terminated
Waiting for Connection
Failed to accept connection
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:205)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at ex1_Getting_your_hands_dirty.ex1.main(ex1.java:55)
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: I don't think `HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found` is a valid status line. Perhaps replace the `x` in `1.x` with `0` or `1`?

Comment: Also I think an HTTP response should have at least 1 header- usually `Content-Length` - and some content in the body would be a good idea.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen JP LEGUEN ON MY SO!?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - What you doing here?! No one I know in the real world is supposed to find me here!

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Your secret is safe with me.

Comment: i get a blank page now with the strings i write not a 404 page

Comment: this what appears in my browser 
Content-Length: 9Content-Type: text/plainNot Found

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your HTTP response isn't valid.

```
    HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found
```

You should:

- Change the `1.x` to a proper version number, like `1.0`
- Add a response body
- Add at least one header - maybe `Content-Length` and `Content-Type`

Something more like...

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: text/plain

Not Found
```

Comment: i get w white page with what i have written

Comment: i changed this part to be 
output.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \r\n");
          output.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/html \r\n\r\n");
          output.writeBytes("Content-Length: 9");
          output.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain");
             output.writeBytes("Not Found");
with the flush as well but i get this 
Content-Length: 9Content-Type: text/plainNot Found